# too paranoid with PTHREADS?

Tags: c, variables, pthreads, local

Everywhere I've looked, I've found tutorials and examples on using pthreads with the pointer to the argument of for the function call referring to a global variable or a local variable inside the main function.
On the other hand, since I can't use global variables, I have the following code:

```
pthread_t thread;

void *thread_created(void *np);
void function2(int numParam);

void function1(int numParam)
{
    int cond=0;
    ...
    if (cond)
        {
            pthread_attr_t attr;
            pthread_attr_init(&attr);
            pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
            pthread_create(&thread,&attr,thread_created,&numParam);
        }
}

void *thread_created(void *np)
{
    int numParam;
    numParam=*((int *)np);
    function2(numParam);
    return NULL;
}

void function2(int numParam)
{
}
```

However, it seems to me, that under some circumstances, the local variable numParam inside function1 may go out of scope BEFORE the thread gets a chance to get its value. A race condition.
So I modified the code, adding the lines marked with //<--

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;    //<--
pthread_cond_t condition=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;  //<--
pthread_t thread;

void *thread_created(void *np);
void function2(int numParam);

void function1(int numParam)
{
    int cond=0;
    ...
    if (cond)
        {
            pthread_attr_t attr;
            pthread_attr_init(&attr);
            pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);                 //<--
            pthread_create(&thread,&attr,thread_created,&numParam);
            pthread_cond_wait(&condition,&mutex);       //<--
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);               //<--
        }
}

void *thread_created(void *np)
{
    int numParam;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);         //<--
    numParam=*((int *)np);
    pthread_cond_signal(&condition);    //<--
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);       //<--
    function2(numParam);
    return NULL;
}

void function2(int numParam)
{
}
```

Am I being too paranoid? Is there really a race condition here? Or is it that by the time the pthread_create returns, the local variable has already been copied and I can carry on? Is there such a thing as too much paranoia with pthreads? The reason of my asking, is that I have several other future instances like this in my system, and I don't want to clutter it needlessly, and since I haven't seen it anywhere else, I kind of think that my "fix" is overblown.

Regards.

Alfredo Meraz

Comment: Why not just malloc space on the heap for the int? Then when the thread is done with it free it? That way you won't have undefined behaviour of accessing a variable after the return of the function.

Comment: I considered that, even creating a structure adding a flag that would be changed inside the thread, signaling the main thread that the value had been changed.

Comment: I guess I don't really follow what you're trying to do. You want to modify a variable, but you're afraid main() is going to trample over it? If so you need a lock. Just pass a lock and a pointer to the variable in a struct or something then every time you read or write to the variable lock?

Comment: What @ScottyBauer says - stop messing around with flags and mutexes and just malloc the damn parameter already:)

Comment: As for the use of malloc, it's discarded because it can create a more dificult situation to debug and overcome: heap fragmentation in a low resources environment due to an extensive use of memory allocation because of the low resources themselves. As for the flag solution I mentioned: it would mean, put it into an empty loop, which hogs up resources in, again, a low resources environment.

Comment: @ScottyBauer function1 is called A LOT OF TIMES per second. And it creates different threads depending on that parameter. Inside each thread, there's more memory allocation, so a small malloc, might end up with that memory being discarded by the OS. A lot of times per second, multiplied by >6 hours of continuos system operation, and a small oversight like this might end up in the system crashing.

Comment: @AlfredoMeraz You do join/detach the thread once it is finished right? Creating a thread is more expensive than a small malloc. If you free it there is no memory leak.

Comment: @self. I don't join the threads. They are created detached. The main loop basically forgets about the thread.

Comment: Let the `main()` allocate the memory, pass it to the thread and then forget all about it. The thread must simply release the memory before it exits. The alternative to dynamically allocated memory is pre-allocated (and necessarily fixed size) memory (probably an array of structures), which leads to resource exhaustion when there are no free elements left in the array. You have to control which thread is using each element of the array; a thread must indicate when it is finished with its element; the main thread has to search to find a free element for the next thread…that's more error prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a global mutex and condition variable is a really bad way to do this. It basically serializes all thread creation operations. There are several much better ways to pass arguments to a new thread:

1. The best: if your data is a single integer that can be faithfully represented by a cast to `void *` and back, do it that way. This requires no synchronization whatsoever and does not fragment memory. Or if you don't want to make the assumption that you can cast through `void *` like this, you could instead support a smaller range of integer values `0` to `N` via `const char dummy[N];` and passing `dummy+i` to `pthread_create` then subtracting `dummy` from the pointer argument received in the thread start function. This variant is **100% portable**, i.e. required by the C standard to work.
2. Light synchronization: put your thread arguments in a structure, and add a `sem_t` member to the structure. Put the structure on the parent thread's stack (automatic storage in the function calling `pthread_create`). Have the parent thread call `sem_init` before creating the thread and `sem_wait` after `pthread_create` returns. The new thread then calls `sem_post` once it's done accessing the arguments (e.g. copying them to its own local storage) and the parent thread calls `sem_destroy` once `sem_wait` returns. At this point the new thread is no longer using the argument structure so the parent can clobber it, let it go out of scope, etc.
3. Moderate synchronization: `malloc`. The parent allocates storage for the arguments via `malloc` and the new thread is responsible for calling `free`. I consider this moderately heavy synchronization because, even if `malloc` normally tries to use thread-local arenas, there's a fundamental global-synchronization-like cost when memory is allocated in one thread and freed in another (though this cost may be deferred). Of course this method also has potential memory fragmentation costs, and complexity costs from dealing with the allocation failure paths.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have some doubts, thou. If your first option is correct in the sense that there is no race condition, then my first snippet of code is correct as well (I still have the doubt of the existence of the race condition). I discard your third option for what I've written in the other messages. Your second option is what I think is really the answer I was missing. Maybe the conditional variable solution works, but the situation really calls for a semaphore. So I'm accepting your answer. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: No. My first option is passing the argument *by value*. There is no race condition because there is no shared object whatsoever. Your code is passing the address of an object that's being modified (or whose lifetime is ending) in the parent thread. That's completely different.

Comment: WOW... I see what you mean... clever way to "inject" a parameter... never thought of doing it that way... but your right :-)... I'm taking this approach... at least, in the parts where its feasible, like in the one I'm facing right now... Next ocurrances in my system, if they don't fit with this approach, I still have the semaphores available... Thank you very much again :-)

Answer (score 0):

using R. response, this is the final code, in case somebody needs it:

```
pthread_t thread;
sem_t semaphore;

void initialize_semaphore()
{
    sem_init(&semaphore,0,1);
}

void destroy_semaphore()
{
    sem_destroy(&semaphore);
}

void *thread_created(void *np);
void function2(int numParam);

void function1(int numParam)
{
    int cond=0;
    ...
    if (cond)
        {
            pthread_attr_t attr;
            pthread_attr_init(&attr);
            pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
            pthread_create(&thread,&attr,thread_created,&numParam);
            sem_wait(&semaphore);
        }
}

void *thread_created(void *np)
{
    int numParam;
    numParam=*((int *)np);
    sem_post(&semaphore);
    function2(numParam);
    return NULL;
}

void function2(int numParam)
{
}
```

And thanks everyone for your answers.

Regards.

Alfredo Meraz.